# UIAutomaion tool doesn't see text fields

Tags: ios, uitextfield, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I've enabled "Accessibility" property for both TextFields that I have on my view and gave them accessibility labels like "LoginTextField" and "PasswordTextField". When I run `logElementTree` on `mainWindow` in UIAutomation script, I **can** see the text fields in the output, they have `rect` and `value` properties, but don't have `name` properties with labels assigned. And of course, `mainWindow.textFields()["LoginTextField"]` returns invalid object. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set accessibility properties in code, not nib editor, see if that helps.